# Bathroom wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, switch, receptacle

How do I wire 3 switches and 1 GFCI receptacle into one box, and 1 additional receptacle by itself, all on the same circuit?
One switch is a smart switch going to the exhaust fan, one switch is going to vanity, last switch will be going to 2 can lights above my shower.

Comment: Is this all new wiring? Or are you replacing existing switches? Can you upload pictures showing any existing wiring in the switch box? Are these 3 separate switches (i.e., single-gang each) or 3-switches-in-one? Are the can lights rated for over-shower use? If not (possibly even if they are) they may need GFCI protection where the vanity lights and the exhaust fan (if not over the shower) do not.

Comment: Replacing switches, I just unwired all that was there and figured I would start fresh... I was hoping to place the 3 individual switches and the GFCI receptacle all in one box as soon as you enter the room to the right by the vanity’s location...

Comment: Did you tag/label the wires to show how they were connected previously?

Comment: There was one power source coming up from from basement fuse box, this bathroom is on my second floor, they had one switch for the vanity lights and one switch for the exhaust fan...

Comment: So the receptacles are new and the shower can lights are new? Is it a 15A or 20A circuit?

Comment: Are there any other things on this circuit - e.g., lights or receptacles in other rooms?

Comment: I apologize I am not at the property at the moment, but the can lights are new, I am rehabbing the entire bathroom, so I can pretty much follow any suggestions

Comment: Generally speaking a bathroom can either have its own 20A dedicated circuit (for receptacles or receptacles + lights) or it can share a 20A circuit for receptacles with other bathrooms (but not other rooms). Fixing what is there you can get away with a 15A circuit, but not if you are doing a full rehab. So that is a key question before continuing. If this circuit already handled receptacles then it is different. If you have *another* circuit for receptacles then you can have this one too, but I believe any new and/or changed (more than straight replacement) must be 20A.

Comment: Thank you very much, I know everyone is busy so I just want to say I really appreciate your time and support!

Comment: I am headed over there shortly I will check to see if anything else is sharing this circuit.

Comment: I suggest you ask one or more questions that are more specific.  There are a lot of topics that are *possibly* relevant here, and this isn't the place for an A to Z tutorial.  A great place to start for that would be youtube, or a book.  You'll find on youtube professionals entirely rewiring rooms and covering all the things you need to know.  Is there anything specific you are unsure of and would like help with?

Comment: Get pictures of the switch box while you are at it. You'd be amazed how much some of the pros (I'm an amateur) can figure out from a picture.

Comment: Since there is existing wiring we need a photo of the wires in the box or a better description. Today you can wire everything in a bathroom on 1 20 amp circuit and be code compliant but you may only have a 15 amp circuit. 
This is when we say code when the home was built but a 15 amp will be fine and we can help out as your power is coming in at the box but the wiring to the lights and fan single cable or x3 cables a photo or better description is needed.

Comment: For example an interesting question, if you ask it, is how to combine dissimilar things like a smart switch, a GFCI outlet, and ordinary switches in a multi-gang box.   An easy answer is "buy Decora everything" ... but not everyone loves that answer and then some boxes become very crowded.  That's just one tiny question you might as that would work nicely in these forums.

Answer (score -2):

You can't do that according to NEC. You need a dedicated circuit for receptacle/s and it must be GFCI protected. You can add a GFCI receptacle (dedicated circuit) and branch of that GFCI receptacle to another receptacle.

If you still want to do it ( I DO NOT recommend it), you can take your source wire and add some pigtails to it to go to other switches, and from switches, new wires to your lights etc.. According to NEC, all electrical boxes must have a ground and natural wires, just keep that in mind. Also, source circuit is almost guarantied to be 15A shared with some other light fixtures in the house.

If your drywall is off and your house is single story house, it is very easy to add another circuit. If you are going to do this, do it right the first time.

Comment: You **can** do that according to NEC. You can either have "everything in one bathroom on one circuit" or "share receptacle circuit between bathrooms but no other rooms". We don't have enough information from OP to know yet whether it is 15A or shared with other lights. Also OP already said it is a two story (plus basement) house, so "single story" does not apply - and even in a single story, adding another circuit is not always so easy - actually easier if it is unfinished basement + another story.

Comment: NEC now requires at least two dedicated circuits for each bathroom:

    A 20-amp receptacle circuit for plug-in appliances. All receptacles must be AFCI and GFCI-protected
    Light fixtures and wall switches must be on a separate circuit. A 15-amp circuit is minimum, but this is often a 20-amp circuit, especially if there is a heat lamp integrated into this circuit. The vent fan may be powered by this circuit. 
    A separate circuit is required for a whirlpool tub or any other large fixture or appliance in the bathroom.

Comment: What is the NEC source for needing separate circuits for lights vs. receptacles? What year did that start?

Comment: Here is some more info: https://www.jadelearning.com/blog/bathroom-branch-circuits-in-the-2020-nec/

Comment: According to that reference, the restriction does *not* apply if the 20A circuit only feeds the one bathroom - see the part "The Exception – What Has Not Changed for the 2020 Code Cycle". Plus many places are not on NEC 2020 yet. So it still gets back to: Does this circuit feed other bathrooms? and What version of NEC?